# What's the difference between PlayReady/Widevine and ClearKey?

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, drm

Like the title states, what is the difference between PlayReady/Widevine and ClearKey? Is PlayReady/Widevine better than ClearKey?

Answer (score 14):

ClearKey is a free alternative to commercial DRM solutions for MPEG-DASH content (MPEG-CENC compliant), but as it is only an encryption solution it does not offer the same level of protection as PlayReady, Widevine or Fairplay.

[Opinion:] If you need a complete DRM solution then working with a provider who supports an integrated DRM solution for origin and playback (eg BuyDRM or Ooyala) is going to provide more protection

- Widevine: Widevine is a Hollywood grade DRM technology initially developed by Widevine Technologies and acquired by Google in 2010. Widevine is natively supported on a broad range of devices and browsers such as Google Chrome Browser, Android, Chromecast, etc.
- PlayReady: PlayReady was developed by Microsoft and is one of major DRM systems available, with broad device support, sophisticated features, and has been used for very large scale events such as the Olympics in Sochi, Russia.
- Fairplay: Fairplay is designed for Apple HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) supporting playback on devices such as iPhone, iPad, Apple TV and Mac OS X. Fairplay is also used as Content Decryption Module (CDM) of the Safari browser. This enables HTML5 native playback of (non-standard) DRM encrypted Fairplay streams without plugins in that browser.

Comment: What if you deliver your "ClearKey"s over HTTPS? Would that make it as secure as other DRMs?

Comment: @dune.rocks no, because the other three are more than just encryption, they have hooks into certified hardware to control the ability to actually play the content. For instance in an HDMI playback situation, the richer DRM schemes can refuse to play back unless the connected device his HDCP compliant etc. ClearKey is a good solution, but if your requirements are for full end-to-end protection you'd need to go for certified solutions that work at a lower level...

Answer (score 8):

The main differences between clear key and the 'normal' DRM's (which Offbeatmammal has nicely summarised) are:

- clear key does not encrypt the key itself. It is simply plain text, 'in the clear'
- No special client side content protection is required to play back the content

To explain the first point, most DRM systems are essentially mechanisms to get a key from a key server to the player device, without anyone being able to intercept or read the key. If someone was able to read the key then they could unencrypt the content. To achieve this DRM systems encrypt the key itself before sending it. For clear key, the key is not encrypted like this.

The second point relates to a secure or protected media path through the client device. This means hardware and/or software in the client device or browser which accepts the encrypted content and the encrypted key and then plays back the content directly to the output device without any input or possibility to copy by any other parts of the system or any other software. Again, clear key does not have this.

Comment: "The second point": do you mean DRM powered can detect screen recordings and prevent it ? is that applicable to shaka player

Comment: Its more the OS that recognises that part of the display is protected and will not allow it be included in screen recordings (or at least should not allow it). You can usually see this if you try ti take a screen shot of one of the popular paid for video streaming services on a Mobile for high value content like 4K. Note that the DRMs provide different levels of protection and secure media path is not a requirement for some - browser players are often lower protection levels. This is one reason 4K may only be available on certain browsers and devices for a given service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to protect your key basically, Key protection is a smart process, Using ssl servers and encryption of key itself and decrypting it when required is important. Do decrypt the key you need a passkey. That you have to kept secure. Use AES with IV and salt to protect key and decrypt it at run time only. passkey need to be user specific or hardware specific. use keystore in android. or a special keygen function that is safe from decompile.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).